# Is it possible to run mpiexec as a subprocess of an mpiexec'd program?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, mpich

I have a program A that is run with mpiexec. This program normally runs in parallel, but in one of the execution patterns, it may invoke an external program B which is also MPI enabled. Of course, every instance of A will end up invoking one instance of B if B is invoked as serial. If invoked parallel, every instance of A will invoke a parallel B.

One possible solution is to have A's master node invoke a parallel B, leaving the other A's processes idle, but of course I need to carry over the mpiexec options from the user command line invocation of A (including any quirks, e.g. PBS interaction) to the inner B invocation. This is as far as I see not trivial, nor dealing nicely with different MPI implementation (e.g. MPICH vs Open MPI).

Does anyone have experience with this kind of problem?

Comment: How about the built-in process management in MPI? The nice thing is that the DRM interaction is automatically being taken care of since the initial A's `mpiexec` is the one that would spawn the processes in B.

Comment: @HristoIliev: You might be on to something, could you detail a bit more about process management in MPI?

Comment: Take a look at the [Process Creation and Management](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi22-report/node201.htm#Node201) chapter of the MPI standard. There are some examples floating around Stack Overflow - just search for `MPI_Comm_spawn`.

Comment: @HristoIliev: this is _really_ interesting. Thanks. I will explore it further and if it works, please come back to add it as an answer. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without using the dynamic process management of MPI 2 and above. You should use MPI call like MPI_COMM_SPAWN or MPI_COMM_SPAWN_MULTIPLE to create new MPI processes. If you use a fork and exec or similar function to start a new mpiexec command, your new process will not be MPI enable and any call to MPI_Init will fails. 
I have experiences that in a project.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't matter if it is possible - it is a terrible idea.  Use MPI_Comm_spawn(_multiple) as noted by others.

And I believe there are at least some networks where this usage will not work and thus it is not portable.

Comment: Terrible or not, that's what I need to provide. Besides, I don't see a lot of alternative when you have to run a script that spawns a process.